# How can you make a drop down menu disappear after you click on an option?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have just a small dropdown menu and I would like to be able to make it so the drop down menu disappears when I click on one of the options (not the button, but just the menu you get when you hover over the button).  I've been looking around for solutions to this, but I can't seem to find any answers.

```js
function changeType(str) {
  document.getElementById("selectType").innerHTML = str;
  document.getElementById("selectType").value = str;
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #360363;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  min-width: 120px;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  margin-top: 0px;
  min-width: 120px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #4B0082;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button id="selectType" class="dropbtn" value="Choose Color">Choose Color</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a onclick="changeType('Red')" href="#">Red</a>
    <a onclick="changeType('Green')" href="#">Green</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .dropdown-content:active { display:none;}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this via CSS:

```
.dropdown:active .dropdown-content,
.dropdown:focus .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
}
```

Snippet:

```js
function changeType(str) {
  document.getElementById("selectType").innerHTML = str;
  document.getElementById("selectType").value = str;
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #360363;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  min-width: 120px;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  margin-top: 0px;
  min-width: 120px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #4B0082;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.dropdown:active .dropdown-content,
.dropdown:focus .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button id="selectType" class="dropbtn" value="Choose Color">Choose Color</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a onclick="changeType('Red')" href="#">Red</a>
    <a onclick="changeType('Green')" href="#">Green</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: I've been trying to solve the same problem, but the solution given here doesn't work for me.  My dropdown menu has a list of href links and each href link has an onClick function and when a link is clicked, the dropdown menu does disappear, but the onClick function doesn't get called. Without the .dropdown:active style, the onClick function gets called, but the dropdown menu doesn't disappear until the mouse is moved out.